# Simpler way of extracting text from file

Tags: linux, bash, text-processing

I've put together a batch script to generate panoramas using the command line tools used by Hugin.  One interesting thing about several of those tools is they allow multi-core usage, but this option has to be flagged within the command.

What I've come up with so far:

```
#get the last fields of each line in the file, initialize the line counter
results=$(more /proc/cpuinfo | awk '{print ($NF)}')
count=0

#loop through the results till the 12th line for cpu core count
for result in $results; do
  if [ $count == 12 ]; then
    echo "Core Count: $result"
  fi
  count=$((count+1))
done
```

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`result=$(awk 'NR==12{print $NF}' /proc/cpuinfo)`

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question about getting the first/last so many lines, you could use [`head`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?head) and [`tail`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?tail),e.g. :

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | awk '{print ($NF)}' | head -12 | tail -1
```

But instead of searching for the 12th line, how about searching semantically for any line containing cores. For example, some machines may have multiple cores, so you may want to sum the results:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "cores" | awk '{s+=$NF} END {print s}'
```

Comment: AWK can do it all: `awk '/cores/ {s+=$NF} END {print s}' /proc/cpuinfo`

Answer (score 2):

```
count=$(getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN)
```

see [getconf(1)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/toc.htm) and [sysconf(3) constants](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Constants-for-Sysconf.html).

According to the Linux manpage, `_SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN` "may not be standard". My guess is this requires glibc or even a Linux system specifically. If that doesn't work, I'd probably take looking at `/sys/class/cpuid` (perhaps there's something better?) over parsing `/proc/cpuinfo`. None of the above are completely portable.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways:

```
head -n 12 /proc/cpuinfo | tail -1 | awk -F: '{print $2}'
grep 'cpu cores' /proc/cpuinfo | head -1 | awk -F: '{print $2}'
```

and so on.

But I must note that you take only the information from the first section of `/proc/cpuinfo` and I am not sure that that is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

And if the cpuinfo changes its format ;) ? Maybe something like this will be better:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo|sed -n 's/cpu cores\s\+:\s\+\(.*\)/\1/p'|tail -n 1
```

And make sure to sum the cores. Mine has got like 12 or 16 of them ;)

Answer (score 0):

unsure what you are trying to do and why what ormaaj said above wouldn't wouldn't work either.  my instinct based on your description would have been much simpler along the lines of.

```
grep processor /proc/cpuinfo  | wc -l
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that the constant in my answer is non-portable (according to the Linux manpage). (Then, so is procfs). Will clarify.